# How to get a transaction details using invoice number?

Tags: authorize.net

We are using authorize.net for payments in our checkout but in some cases we are not getting any response from authorize.net so we are unable to store transaction details in our database and also customers are being charged more than once. So to resolve this we are planning to get the transaction details before sending the payment but we don't have **transaction id** in our side, so we need a API to get the transaction details using invoice number.

I have searched lot in the API documentation but couldn't able to find it, so any reference might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot retrieve transaction information through their API with an invoice number. If you know the dates, and other helpful information about these missing transactions, you can use their Transaction Reporting API to get those day's transaction and retrieve the necessary information that way.

One way to avoid this in the future is to use either [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/)<sup>1</sup> or their new [Webhooks API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html) to get notified whenever a payment is made (and any other event you specify).

<sup>1</sup> I am the author of that article.